# Cannot load .pkl persisted model when .ipynb is in subdirectory

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, pickle, joblib

I created `grid_search.pkl` file for [model persitence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) after fitting it in Jupyter Notebook like this:

`joblib.dump(grid_search, 'grid_search_rf.pkl', compress=3)`

after a while, I have moved my `.ipynb` file to subdirectory called `notebooks` and also I did some refactoring to my modules in parent directory of `notebooks`

now when trying to load this `grid_search.pkl` file into my notebook which is in subdirectory (of parent directory with contain my modules) like this:

`grid_search = joblib.load('../grid_search_rf.pkl')`

I get [this weird error](https://pastebin.com/0GwnbQQp) about one of my modules which doesn't seems to be related.

However when jupyter notebook is directly in my parent dir with all `.py` modules and `.pkl` files, `grid_search.pkl` file is loaded correctly.

Why? How can I load this `.pkl` file while having `.ipynb` file in subdirectory of that parent dir?

**EDIT**: I have added class `TextParser` (based on weird error) which I have removed during refactoring in one of my module and now everything works fine and I can load `grid_search.pkl` from parent directory into jupyter notebooks as they are in subdirectory `notebooks`, can someone please explain this behaviour of pickling?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Pickle file references some module that is not on your `PYTHONPATH`. Try inserting the following code before loading the Pickle:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```